# DataTables filters for each column with multiple filter options

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have been trying to come up with a solution similar to Datatables searchBuilder but for each column, specific to the data in that column, sort of like how its done in PowerApps dynamics. I want be able to hit a filter icon, that I have created in the Datatables headers, that would dropdown or popup filter options based on that column. searchBuilder is close but I want the data part to be auto populated based on the column and just have the condition and value sections in my dropdown. like seen below

this is sort of what im looking for..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0DDI.png)

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name

            <div class="fliterDD">

                <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li>
                        <div class="checkbox">

                            Filter in Here


                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </th>
        <th>Position

            <div class="fliterDD">

                <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li>
                        <div class="checkbox">

                            Filter in Here


                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </th>
        <th>Office

            <div class="fliterDD">

                <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li>
                        <div class="checkbox">

                            Filter in Here


                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </th>
        <th>Age

            <div class="fliterDD">

                <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li>
                        <div class="checkbox">

                            Filter in Here


                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </th>
        <th>Start date

            <div class="fliterDD">

                <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li>
                        <div class="checkbox">

                            Filter in Here


                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </th>
        <th>Salary

            <div class="fliterDD">

                <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li>
                        <div class="checkbox">

                            Filter in Here


                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$4,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$3,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$4,525</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$4,080</td>
    </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>




<script>


    $(document).ready( function () {

        var reorderStart = -1;  // Save start position

        var table = $('#example').DataTable({


            colReorder: {
                enable: false
            },

            language: {
                searchBuilder: {
                    button: 'Filter',
                }
            },

            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [


                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: 'Export to Excel',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },


                'createState', 'savedStates', 'searchBuilder'


            ],

            columns: [
                {name: 'Name'},
                {name: 'Position'},
                {name: 'Office'},
                {name: 'Age'},
                {name: 'Start Date'},
                {name: 'Salary'},
            ],
        });



    } );


</script>
```